Error while filling the input in the Preline UI component
Currently I'm using PrelineUI("preline": "^2.0.1",) and tailwindcss("tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",). I have more than one input in an preline accordion component. Even though I haven't made any checks, inputs sometimes do not allow English characters to be written when trying to fill them. I don't know what's causing the problem.
If inputs are autofilled, an error message appears.
When you try to fill it manually, for example with "A", a warning appears in the console with the phrase 'KeyCode: KeyA'.


if (e && (c.DROPDOWN_ACCESSIBILITY_KEY_SET.includes(t.code) || 4 === t.code.length && t.code[t.code.length - 1].match(/^[A-Z]*$/)) && !t.metaKey && !e.element.menu.querySelector("input:focus"))
                        switch (console.log("Key code:", t.code),
                        t.code) {
                        case "Escape":
                            e.element.menu.querySelector(".hs-select.active") || (t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onEscape(t));
                            break;
                        case "Enter":
                            e.element.menu.querySelector(".hs-select button:focus") || e.element.menu.querySelector(".hs-collapse-toggle:focus") || this.onEnter(t);
                            break;
                        case "ArrowUp":
                            t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onArrow();
                            break;
                        case "ArrowDown":
                            t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onArrow(!1);
                            break;
                        case "Home":
                            t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onStartEnd();
                            break;
                        case "End":
                            t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onStartEnd(!1);
                            break;
                        default:
                            t.preventDefault(),
                            this.onFirstLetter(t.key)
                        }
                }



Preline Warning
As a result, I will be very happy if I fill in the inputs successfully and do not receive the warning and this error that I receive from the library.

Ask question with proper inputs @ArdaAlkan

Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean by "proper inputs"?

Removing the 'Dropdown' component with the Auto-Close feature helped solve the problem.
